# How can I display create tab for a new queue on management console?

Tags: activemq-artemis

Artemis version : 2.10

I want to create a new queue using the management console, but the "Create" button isn't displayed.

How can I display this button?

[image: console]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queues are mapped to addresses so in order to create a queue in the management console you need to click on an address. It will look something like this:
[image: Create Queue]
If you want to create an *address* then click on the *addresses* item in the tree in the left-hand pane. You should see something like this:
[image: Create Address]
I'm using ActiveMQ Artemis 2.10.1 here.

Comment: Create tab wasn't displayed next to Chart tab on my management console. But, after reloading browser, it was displayed! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we have to refresh page to see Create task. It is not friendly or maybe a bug of UI side

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?